# Aggregating Data from same value from different row in Spotfire

Tags: expression, calculated-columns, spotfire, intersect

I've some clinical data that needs some tricky calculations.

[Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDxUB.png)

I have a column called "LabCode" and another "Days" which is my aggregate data/Measure.The third column is my expected output after the aggregations.

The labcode are the high (H) or Low (L) dosage from the test results from an individual on the trial.

The doctors want to know how many days the person was on low dosage before high dosage and vice versa.

I want OVER Function expression that can show the results in yellow highlights.

Thanks for your help.